# Vim match containedin not working as expected

Tags: vim, c, syntax, comments

I have tried to extend the C syntax in Vim with the example in the manual.

First I launch vim without any config:

```
vim -u NONE test.c
```

Then I load the c-syntax and create my extension

```
syntax on
syntax keyword myword HELP containedin=cComment contained
highlight myword guibg=red
```

code:

```
1: /* HELP */
2: int main(int argc, char **argv) {
3:     int HELP = 0;
4:     if(HELP);
5: }
```

HELP is highlighted on line 1 as expected. It is also highlighted on line 4, is there some explanation for this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to find out which syntax group "occupies" the `HELP` in the third line that is not covered by your syntax rule. `:syn list` shows all active groups, but it's easier when you install the [SyntaxAttr.vim - Show syntax highlighting attributes of character under cursor](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=383) plugin.

SyntaxAttr tells me the `cBlock` syntax matches there; this needs to be included in your extension, too:

```
syntax keyword myword HELP containedin=cComment,cBlock contained
```

Comment: If I `:call SyntaxAttr()` when the cursor is within the parentheses, it only gives me `group: myword guibg=red(#ff0000)`. I do not get why I should include `cBlock`, since I want to restrict the number of places where the myword highlighting is used.

Comment: The `cBlock` encompasses everything within `{`...`}` and prevents the match. This definition is found in `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/c.vim`. It would obscure the `HELP` in line 4, too; however, that is contained in `cParen` which `contains=ALLBUT,...` The `ALL` makes this include your `myword`, and so it is highlighted without you having to `containedin=cParen`.